# Has been or had been

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect, british-english

I am writing to my boss about just completed task.

> The document has been created and tested. The same was delivered to client.

Here what should be Used had been or has been. Since in second sentence I am using past "was" So I am confused

Comment: Just say *The document has been created, tested, and delivered to [the] client*. Your use of ***the same*** is a dated literary/legal one which doesn't sit well in the context of modern internal company emails.

Comment: You would only use ***had*** if you were referring to some other point in time in the past when something else happened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Has been** is the *Present perfect* tense of *be*.

> He/she/it **has been** living above me for over a year.
>
> - (He/she/it still lives above me)

**Had been** is the *Past perfect* tense of *be*

> He/she/it **had been** living above me for over a year.
>
> - (He/she/it no longer lives above me)

For your situation:

> The document **has been** created, tested, and delivered to [the] client.
>
> - This would be correct if the status of the document is "created, tested, and delivered" and the status is still the same. This would most likely be the best fit for your situation.
>
> The document **had been** created, tested, and delivered to [the] client.
>
> - This would be correct if the status was previously "created, tested, and delivered" but now the status has changed. Although a rare and unlikely case, the document could've been recalled or taken back from the client.